# How can I set the number of ticks with Image_Graph?

Tags: php, graph, pear

I am using Image_Graph (maintained at pear.veggerby.dk)to generate some graphs. I've been trying to use the methods described on this page 
http://pear.php.net/reference/Image_Graph-0.2.1/Image_Graph/Image_Graph_Axis.html
to manipulate ticks but none of them seem to even exist in the 0.7.2 install. Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for 0.7.2 instead :)

http://pear.php.net/reference/Image_Graph-0.7.2/Image_Graph/Axis/Image_Graph_Axis.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but unfortunately I got tired of lack of docs on Image_Graph and switched my project over to jpGraph: http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/